# Sort elements by frequency in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, frequency

Input:

```
$result = Array
    (
        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "ლუკა ქურასბედიანი",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "z",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "z",
            ),

       Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "z",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "z",
            ), 
        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),
        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),
        Array(
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "z",
            ),

    );
```

I want sort elements by frequency (by "parrent_club_hash_id" ).

There are `11-x 7-y` and `5-z` so i want output like this:

```
$result = Array
    (
        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "ლუკა ქურასბედიანი",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

       Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "x",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "y",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "z",
            ),

        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "z",
            ), 
        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "z",
            ),
        Array
            (
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "z",
            ),
        Array(
                "name" => "",
                "squad_member_hash_id" => "",
                "parrent_club_hash_id" => "z",
            ),

    );
```

Comment: I assume you mean "parent", not "parrent"?

Comment: yes yes "parent", sorry for that...

Comment: incidentally - what have you tried so far as I don't see any attempt at solving this above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the frequencies of your values:

```
$values = array_count_values(array_column($result, 'parrent_club_hash_id'));
```

Then sort by those frequencies using a custom sort:

```
usort($result, function ($x, $y) use ($values) {
    // $y is first because you need descending sort
    return $values[$y["parrent_club_hash_id"]] - $values[$x["parrent_club_hash_id"]];
});
```

Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6265192e677641afbc21e899d97f252c14b5402f

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is what i need.